# ignore differences in syntax in beyondcompare

Tags: version-control, compare, beyondcompare

In a branch of code I have changed all of the code from `obj.varname` to `obj("varname")` and when I compare the code I would like to ignore these differences since `varname` is the same.

I have a regular expression that I think I need but unfortunately can't get the comparison to be ignored using Beyond Compare from Scooter

`^obj\("\w*"\)|obj\.\w*$`

I am following this tutorial http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_unimportantv3

So my question: is this even possible with beyond compare?  If yes, please share a solution including either instructions or post your screenshots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beyond Compare 3's Professional edition supports this through its **Text Replacements** feature. If you've already purchased a Standard edition license you need to revert to trial mode to test it:  http://www.scootersoftware.com/suppo...?zz=kb_evalpro

1. Load your two files in the Text Compare.
2. Open the **Session Settings** dialog from the the **Session** menu, and on the **Replacements** tab click **New** to create a new replacement.
3. In the **Text to find** edit, use `(\w+)\.(\w+)`
4. In the **Replace with** edit, use `$1("$2")`
5. Check the **Regular expression** checkbox.

---

The alternative would be to mark any instance of `obj.varname` and `obj("varname")` as unimportant.  The basic steps would be this:

1. Load your two files in the Text Compare.
2. Open the **Session Settings** dialog from the **Session** menu, and on the **Importance** tab click the **Edit Grammar...** button.
3. In the next dialog click the **New...** button below the top listbox.
4. Change the **Element name** field to something useful (say, "PropertyAccess").
5. Change the **Category*** to **List**.
6. In the *Text in list** edit, add these two lines:

   `obj.varname`
     `obj("varname")`
7. Click **OK** to close the **Grammar Item** dialog and then click **OK** again to close the *Text Format** grammar item.
8. Uncheck "PropertyAccess" (or whatever you named it) in the **Grammar elements** listbox in the **Session Settings** dialog, then click **OK** to close it.

This approach isn't as flexible or clean.  In the steps above you're matching specific, hardcoded object and variable names, so `obj.varname` is unimportant but `obj.othervar` isn't, even if it's aligned against `obj("othervar")`.  If text on both sides is unimportant the difference will be unimportant; if one side is important it will be an important difference.  So, with the above steps, `obj.varname` and `obj("varname")` will be unimportant everywhere, but it will work correctly since they'll either be matched to other cases that also match those definitions (and thus unimportant) or will be matched to something else that doesn't match that definition, which will be important and will make the difference important.

You can use regular expressions to match more general text categories, but you probably don't want to.  For example, if you wanted to match all text that followed that pattern you could use these two lines instead:

```
\w+\.\w+
\w+\("\w+"\)
```

And then check the **Regular expressions** checkbox in the **Grammar Item** dialog so they're matched that way.

The upside/downside to that is that *any* text that matches those patterns is then unimportant.  `abc.newvar` vs. `def.varname` would be considered an unimportant difference because both sides match the unimportant definition.  That's good for things like comments or whitespace changes, but probably isn't what you want to do here.

Comment: This is so awesome!  The first solution worked like a charm and I discovered a feature I never knew, however the second still does not. If you don't mind post all the grammar defined as important or unimportant so I can repeat.

Comment: @kiev I've updated the answer with more details on the second approach.